# How to compare two objects and return an object that differs

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

How to compare two objects and return an object that differs.

Elements that differ are overwritten by the secondObject.

I want to use EcmaScript6

```
const firtObject = {a:"abc", b:"bcd", c:"cde"}
const secondObject = {b:"fff", c:"cde"}

const returnObject= {a:"abc", b:"fff", c:"cde"}
```

Comment: `Object.assign({}, firstObject, secondObject)` and fix the typo

Comment: Using spread operator: `console.log({...firstObject, ...secondObject})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple spreading:

```js
const firstObject = {a:"abc", b:"bcd", c:"cde"}
const secondObject = {b:"fff", c:"cde"};
const returnObject = { ...firstObject, ...secondObject };
console.log(returnObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

You could also use `Object.assign`:

```js
const firstObject = {a:"abc", b:"bcd", c:"cde"}
const secondObject = {b:"fff", c:"cde"};
const returnObject = Object.assign({}, firstObject, secondObject);
console.log(returnObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: No problem @benxmario, if my answer fixed your problem please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have one more question, how to return an object that has been overwritten?

returnObject = {b:"fff"}